# Rigid body wind chime not working as expected

Tags: animation, rigid-body-simulation

I'm trying to do a "wind chime" like model. It's supposed to have multiple shapes connected by rings, like the image you see. I've assigned rigid bodies to every object and im sim the Mesh collision option, but when I start the simulation, the ring come out of the hole and the piece completly falls. Any idea on how I can maintain them united?[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be succinct, unique and identifying, and summarize what the issue is so that users can at a glance broadly understand what your post is about before opening it. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid any emojis salutations or extraneous text not essential to the question. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and will weight heavily on their decision to open your question, which will directly affect the number of answers you might get.

Comment: Hello, maybe share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: you could give rigid body constraints a try...maybe with type point

Comment: without file or more information it is hard to guess... My guess is either collision margin, or type of collision body, or some different error in simulation

Comment: Good start point would be to always ensure you have ‘Applied Scale’ after resizing and also make sure to set the origin to the Center of Mass for each object (I notice in your image the origin seems to be on the top edge). Look at Rigid Body Constraints as that will be very applicable for such connected objects.

Comment: rings possibly too small compared to the step size of the simulation or you're using convex hull instead of mesh, perhaps?